# Try to enable billing profile on app engine, but failed and charged me 1 dollar

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

Yesterday, I tried to enable billing profile. After I input all of the right credit information and proceed, it just told me

> "Your bank or credit card company has declined the authorization:
>   Invalid Verification code"

I make sure I've input the exact right information and tried again and again, but only failures and charges. GOOGLE charged me C$ 1.10 for 6 times...still stuck in how to enable billing...

I've search all of the app engine page and no way to reach the support...

So, I come here and need you kind guys help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: StackOverflow isn't for billing questions: https://support.google.com/code/contact/cloud_platform_billing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each transaction attempt (in this case, an authorization) is subject to fees - $1.00 for the authorization charge, an $.10 for the transaction. But you'll need to connect with Google to see more specifics on the decline reasons.